# Is there a way to set the time limit for branch and bound in SCIP?

Tags: linear-programming, scip, mixed-integer-programming, scipopt

I was wondering if there is a way to set the upper bound of the time taken to solve a MILP problem but only on the branch and bound time. I was able to find a parameter for the total running time but I am unable to find the parameter that restricts the branch and bound time.

Comment: I would guess you need to do this using a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no parameter that you can set to achieve this. Just to be clear: Do you mean with branch and bound time the solving time without presolving, or do you mean just the time spent on branching?

Comment: Just time spent after the root node. Thanks for the information